# Make telegram video call with specific contact with android programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, call, telegram, mime-types

I want to make start a telegram video call from inside my android app, so I have decompiled the new telegram apk to find the following:

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.profile" />
                <data
                    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call" />
                <data
                    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call.video" />
            </intent-filter>
```

There is something related to `call.video`, but I don't know how to use this `data` element in the code, my only try was to do the following:

```
Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,
                Uri.parse("https://telegram.me/"+contact));
        startActivity(telegram);
```

I expect something like `telegram.setType("video");` or `telegram.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call.video")`.

Is it possible at the end ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I have decompiled the new telegram apk" -- Telegram is [open source](https://github.com/TelegramOrg/Telegram-Android). The more relevant `<intent-filter>` for you would appear to be the one below that one, which shows what Web URLs this activity supports.

Comment: So the following line `<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call.video"/>` is useless to me in my intent ?

Comment: Only if you have a `Uri` whose MIME type matches. Usually a MIME type like that comes from an entry in a `ContentProvider`, not a from a Web URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URI contactID with mimeType which is "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call.video". Looking first **contactID** by number phone:

```
private String getContactIdByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    String contactId = null;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactId;
}
```

then use this *contactID* and *mimeType* to find URI:

```
private Uri getUriFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = null;
    String contactId = getContactIdByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    String mimeTypeTelegram = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.call.video";
    Cursor cursorTelegram = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
            new String[]{contactId, mimeTypeTelegram}, null);
    if (cursorTelegram != null) {
        while (cursorTelegram.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursorTelegram.getString(cursorTelegram.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                uri = Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                break;
            }
        }
        cursorTelegram.close();
    }
    return uri;
}
```

after which use **Intent.ACTION_VIEW**:

```
public void videoCallToTelegramContact(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = getUriFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    Log.d(TAG, uri + "");
    if (uri != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

It would be nice to add a check for the installed 'Telegram', as well as whether the user has allowed the video call.

Comment: Is it possible to send message using the same logic (by phone number, not telegram user id)?

Comment: No, it is impossible, if the call it explicitly opens the application, then the message must be sent in the background. Only deal with it Telegram API or Telegram Bot. Maybe add to your project telegram library - **'TDLib'**.

info: https://core.telegram.org/